# How to compare a FieldGetText with a number?

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript

I have a field that it stores a currency data with the name `pdcPrimasVAFVigor`.

I can get the value with the `FieldGetText` method about `NotesUIDocument` like this:

```
strPrimasVaf = uidoc.Fieldgettext("pdcPrimasVAFVigor")
```

And then I check the value and the type:

```
Msgbox "strPrimasVaf: " + Typename(strPrimasVaf)
```

This messagebox retrievme:

> strPrimasVaf: 122.00 € STRING

If I want to compare strPrimasVaf with any number but the comparision doens't work, then I have tried to convert the data but I always get the next error:

> Type Mismatch in method CoerStrToNum...

**But, what have I tried?**

I have tried to convert the string value before to compare like this:

```
Dim intPrimasVaf As Integer
intPrimasVaf = CInt(strPrimasVaf)    ' Error

Dim dblPrimasVaf As Double
dblPrimasVaf = CInt(strPrimasVaf)    ' Error

Dim curPrimasVaf As Currency
curPrimasVaf = CInt(strPrimasVaf)    ' Error
```

Include I have try to change the format like this:

```
Dim x As Variant
x = Format(strPrimasVaf, "General Number")
```

Any advice or solution within using `FieldGetText`?

Comment: If you really must use uidoc, you could try Cdbl(). Otherwise, use the backend document, see below.

Comment: I tryed also Cdbl() but with any result.

Comment: Remove the € before the  conversion...

Comment: @umeli i tryed with `Format` but or I couldnt or I dont know to do it.

Comment: strPrimasVaf = uidoc.Fieldgettext("pdcPrimasVAFVigor")
strPrimasVaf=cdbl(fulltrim(join(split(strPrimasVaf,"€"),"")))

Some other issues could be if your seperator is not a dot

Comment: @umeli your solution is perfect, if you want post the answer to mark it as solved. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the € from the string with something like:

```html
strPrimasVaf = uidoc.Fieldgettext("pdcPrimasVAFVigor")
strPrimasVaf=cdbl(fulltrim(join(split(strPrimasVaf,"€"),"")))
```

Answer (score 5):

My advice: work with the backend document object.
Add

```vba
Dim doc as Notesdocument

Dim dblPrimasVaf As Double

Set doc=uidoc.document

dblPrimasVaf=doc.pdcPrimasVAFVigor(0)
```

No conversion needed.

Comment: Thanks for your advice but i need to do with uidoc.

Comment: Why? Working with the doc makes development so much easier. I’ve been developing Notes for over 20 years, and I almost never use fieldgettext. There is no reason to avoid doc and stick with uidoc at all.

Comment: I cant use doc in a class, i dont know why, but i cant, I recieve an error form debuger  when i set this object. Thats the reason, but I appreciate a lot your help and advice.